# How to click a button that's only visible when hovered over?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm tinkering with an applescript that would clear notifications from Notification Center. At this point cannot figure out a way to click the **clear button**.

[image: "X" button]

You see, the button only appears if cursor is hovering on the row of the app, or rows below that belongs to this app. I do:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer" ¬ 
to click menu bar item "Notification Center" of menu bar 2

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Notification Center" ¬
to value of attribute "AXChildren" of UI element 1 of row 2 of table 1 of ¬
scroll area 1 of window "NotificationTableWindow"
```

Result:

```
{static text "iTunes" of UI element "iTunes" of row 2 of table 1 of ¬
scroll area 1 of window "NotificationTableWindow" of application process ¬
"NotificationCenter" of application "System Events"}
```

But if I strategically place the cursor beforehand, I get:

```
{static text "iTunes" of (ditto), button 1 of (ditto)}
```

`button 1` is what I'm searching for. So far I tried three ways that didn't work out, listed from dumb to less dumb:

#### 1) Keyboard Navigation

I tried to navigate down the list with `key code 125`. This doesn't make the button visible. While there, I tried a myriad of Delete combos. Nothing seems to delete notification entries.

#### 2) `click at (x,y)` from System Events

On a 1280x800 screen, the button has an `AXFrame` of:

```
{x=1256.00 y=77.00 w=16.00 h=16.00}
```

which gives it a center of `{1264, 85}`, so:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Notification Center"
click at {1264, 85}
value of attribute "AXChildren" of UI element 1 of row 2 of table 1 of ¬
scroll area 1 of window "NotificationTableWindow"
end tell
```

This, unsurprisingly, doesn't work.

#### 3) `select` from System Events

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Notification Center" to ¬
tell window "NotificationTableWindow" to tell scroll area 1 to tell table 1 ¬
to tell row 2
select UI element 1
value of attribute "AXChildren" of UI element 1
end tell
```

Still, I only get `static text 1` that is the app name. `button 1` that is the clear button is nowhere to be found.

**Does anyone know how to click this button - a button that only appears when hovered over?**

Comment: I would still like an answer to this question

Comment: Figured it out: https://gist.github.com/jenikm/999eacaf62353e53ec13e5dcc3396f6e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer your question (the **GUI Scripting**, I'm not on **Yosemite**), but :

To clear all notifications (works on **Maverick**, I don't know on **Yosemite**), this script delete notifications from the database in "`~/Library/Application Support/NotificationCenter`" folder :

```
set notifCenterFolder to (path to application support from user domain as text) & "NotificationCenter:"
tell application "System Events" to set tDB to POSIX path of (first file of folder notifCenterFolder whose name extension is "db")
do shell script "/usr/bin/sqlite3 " & (quoted form of tDB) & " 'DELETE FROM notifications' && osascript -e 'quit application \"NotificationCenter\" ' && killall usernoted"
```

--

To clear notifications for a specific application (**iTunes** as example):

```
set iTunesPath to "/Applications/iTunes.app"
set notifCenterFolder to (path to application support from user domain as text) & "NotificationCenter:"
tell application "System Events" to set tDB to POSIX path of (first file of folder notifCenterFolder whose name extension is "db")
do shell script "/usr/bin/sqlite3 " & (quoted form of tDB) & " 'delete FROM notifications where app_id = (select app_id FROM app_source where last_known_path = \"" & iTunesPath & "\")' && osascript -e 'quit application \"NotificationCenter\" ' && killall usernoted"
```

--

On **Yosemite**, this file is in another folder  --> `/var/folder/...` see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156832/where-osx-10-10-notification-center-settings-are-stored)

Use this AppleScript on **Yosemite** :

```
do shell script "cd `getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR`com.apple.notificationcenter/db/ && /usr/bin/sqlite3 db 'DELETE FROM notifications' && osascript -e 'quit application \"NotificationCenter\" ' && killall usernoted"
```

Comment: This is no `~/Library/Application Support/NotificationCenter` in Yosemite, according on my system at least. I also did a quick `find` for `"*.db"`. No result is related to notification center.